# tableau - color text dimension according to other dimension value

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 dimensions (one is BUG_ID, the other is severity).
I have defined a specific color for each possible severity (blocker == red, normal= orange...)
I am using a table and I want to color the BUG_ID dimension value (the text) according to the color defined for reach severity for example:
[image: color formatting]

I have tried several things but cannot figure out how to do it.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally Tableau is a data visualisation tool, so if you want to create graphs of any kind it's great. If you want to create a table and format text, stick to Excel!

You can drag all dimensions you would like to have in the rows shelf. eg: `[Description]` and `[Status]`. Now you can drag the `[BUG_ID]` onto "Text" in the Marks pane. That will display the bug ID, but it will be on the right of all other dimensions. And you won't be able to change it.
To color it, just drag `[Severity]` onto colur and choose the colors you want.